# Using the value of exists?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am writing a custom provider in Puppet using ruby. My puppet script

```
storagearray { 'create a volume':
  type      => 'volume',
  ensure    => absent,
  volname   => "vol-23",
  sizemb    => 100,
}
```

In the provider code

```
   def exists?
      allVolumes = returnAllVolumes()
      allVolumes.each do |volume|
          if resource[:volname].eql? volume["name"]
            puts "Volume " + volume["name"] + " already exists"
            return volume["id"]
          end
      end      
      return nil
    end

def destroy
    volId = returnVolId(resource[:volname])
    doDelete("/v1/volume?id="+volId)
end
```

Now I found out, before calling destroy, the script actually calls exists? which returns a vol id. Is there a way I can catch it inside destroy avoiding a call to returnVolId ?

Comment: This isn't meant to answer your question, but typically in ruby a method ending in `?` returns a boolean

Comment: Thanks @ptierno I don't have a lot of ruby experience. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: I'm unclear about what you're asking. Could you elaborate a little? Are you trying to avoid calling exists? or do something different in destroy? Or both.

Comment: Style guide for ruby, please dont do camelCase do snake_case.

Comment: Elaboration would be great. Also, as mentioned, that `exists?` should be returning a boolean, so your `return volume["id"]` should be changed. Am I correct that this is someone else's code that you are attempting to reuse?